# why filters are not working in view query alter?

Tags: 8

why filters are not working in  view query alter here is my code what i am doing wrong:

```
     if ($view->id() == 'answer_key_form' && $view- 
     >getDisplay()->display['id'] == 'page_2') {

     $competetive_array=array('234','235' );



           foreach ($query->where as &$condition_group) {
           foreach ($condition_group['conditions'] as 
            &$condition) {


            if ($condition['field'] == ' 

 node__field_akf_select_product.field_akf_select_product_target_id') {

      $condition = array(
        'field' => 'node__field_akf_select_product.field_akf_select_product_target_id',
        'value' => $competetive_array,
        'operator' => 'IN',
      );

    }
  }
}
```

if my url arguments are www.test.com/field_akf_select_product_target_id=234 its giving me same result if i pass any random no in url parameter like field_akf_select_product_target_id=886 still its giving same result it should show no result found..

Comment: Is the missing quote (after `'235`) just a typo in the question?

Comment: i edited my question but still i am getting same result i want to filter result by product id which are 234 or 235 the values are comming in array if 235 dont have any associated node ,in view result no record found should show like = condition

Comment: Is that your complete code for first if statement and please mention the error if you found any?

Comment: Why would it be different? In your code, I don't see any conditional based on product ID. Anyhow, what exactly are you trying to do? you might be able to accomplish your goal without using query_alter

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by myself ,i have added condition for operator where i was doing mistake ,on first page load **"IN"** operator will work then **"=" on selection of select list :**

```
  function get_purchased_product_id() {
  //Get current user id 
  $user_id = \Drupal::currentUser()->id();

  $uid = ($user_id ==1)? 267 :$user_id;

  $query_get_product_name =  db_select('commerce_order', 'c');
  $query_get_product_name->join('commerce_order_item', 'ci', 'c.order_id = ci.order_id');
  $query_get_product_name->join('commerce_product_variation_field_data', 'cf', 'ci.purchased_entity = cf.variation_id');
  $query_get_product_name->fields('c', ['uid']);
  $query_get_product_name->fields('ci', ['purchased_entity']);
  $query_get_product_name->fields('cf', ['product_id','title']);
  $query_get_product_name->condition('c.uid', $uid,'=');
  $query_get_product_name->condition('c.state', 'completed','=');
  $result = $query_get_product_name->execute();

  $arr_var=array();

  foreach ($result as $value ){
  $arr_var[]= $value->product_id;
   }
  return $arr_var;

 } 


 function classroom_common_views_query_alter(ViewExecutable $view, QueryPluginBase $query) {

if ($view->id() == 'answer_key_form_management' && $view->getDisplay()->display['id'] == 'page_2') {
  //function call to get product id of purchased item by current user
  $arr_product_id = get_purchased_product_id();

  $product_target_id = Drupal::request()->query->get('field_akfp_select_product_target_id');
  if(!empty($product_target_id)){
     $arr_product_id = $product_target_id;
  }
  $operator = !empty($product_target_id) ? '=' : 'IN';

foreach ($query->where as &$condition_group) {
      foreach ($condition_group['conditions'] as &$condition) {
        if ($condition['field'] == 'node__field_akfp_select_product.field_akfp_select_product_target_id') {

          $condition = array(
            'field' => 'node__field_akfp_select_product.field_akfp_select_product_target_id',
            'value' =>  $arr_product_id,
            'operator' => $operator,
          );

        }
      }
    }
}
```